# setting default syntax for sublime doesn't work

Tags: matlab, syntax, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Whenever I open a .m file the default syntax is objective-c but I want to change that to matlab. So when I open a .m file I go to

> view -> syntax -> open all with current extension as..

and choose matlab. After that if I open another .m file the default syntax is matlab. But if I close sublime and open it again the default syntax is back to objective-c.

I added objective-c to ignore syntax list but now it opens .m files as plain text. Is there another way to set default syntax for a file extension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why Sublime is doing this, but there's a way around it. Since you're using ST2, it's quite easy. Select **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** to open your `Packages` folder, and open the `Objective-C` subfolder. Open `Objective-C.tmLanguage` in Sublime as an XML file, and comment out (or remove entirely) Line 7:

```xml
<string>m</string>
```

Save the file and close it. Next, open `Objective-C++.tmLanguage` and do the same thing to Line 8:

```xml
<string>M</string>
```

Save and close that file as well. Finally, just to make sure your **`Open all with current extension as...`** command worked, go to `Packages/User` and check for the existence of a file called `MATLAB.sublime-settings`. Open it as a JSON file, and double-check that its contents are as follows:

```json
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "m"
    ]
}
```

If for some reason the file doesn't exist, create it with the above contents and save it. You should now be able to open any `.m` file and have the syntax automatically set to `MATLAB`.

---

**Note for Sublime Text 3 users:**

ST3 does not store its default packages in `Packages` anymore, instead they're in the `Installed Packages` folder (its location varies by OS and type of install) as zipped `.sublime-package` files. To access the contents, install @skuroda's [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin to seamlessly access the contents of these files. Once installed, open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> on OS X) and type ***`prv`*** to bring up the `PackageResourceViewer` options. Select `Extract Package`, scroll down to `Objective-C`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You can now follow the directions above for opening the `Packages/Objective-C` folder and editing the `.tmLanguage` files. The `Packages/User` directory **is** a regular directory, so you don't need to extract it to verify the contents of `MATLAB.sublime-settings`.

Answer (score 6):

In sublime3, view -> syntax -> open all with current extension as.. works if you close then open sublime.

Answer (score 0):

I think why this is happening, at least in Sublime 3 (v3.2.1). After using `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Package` to extract `Matlab` package, I found that in `Matlab.sublime-syntax` in Line 6:

```
  - matlab
```

As `.matlab` is not an extension for matlab functions and scripts, after I changed it to `- m`, Sublime shows `.m` files in MATLAB syntax.